# yii2 url manager rules accept not pattern

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I need configure my Yii2 `UrlManager` rules like this:

1. change `http://domain/site/action` to `http://domain/action`
2. change `http://domain/module/default` to `http://domain/module`

so far what I have done:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<module:(!site)>' => '<module>/default',
        '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
    ],
],
```

when I trying access `module` it return 404. But when I remove `'<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',` access `module` again will show as `module/default` page. So how to solve this?

Comment: When you have url like `http://domain/something` how is the router supposed to know if `something` should be module or action?

Comment: I don't know. so do you have solution for this?

Comment: Not really. There is no generic solution using existing router. You can make explicit routes for all actions in site controller then put generic route for modules as last rule. Another option is to extend `yii\web\UrlRule` and override its `parseRequest` method to check existence of action. Or you can simply add some prefix to your url so you can determine if route belongs to site controller or module. For example use `http://domain/m/something` for modules and `http://domain/something` for actions in site controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
'<action:(about|contact)>' => 'site/<action>',
```

insted of this

```
'<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
```

and it will not work then change sequence of rules

```
'rules' => [
    '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>', <-----------it will be first
    '<module:(!site)>' => '<module>/default',
],
```

Comment: ```'<action:(about|contact)>' => 'site/<action>',``` i want all action in site controller not only `about` and `contact`

Comment: if I change ```'<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',``` to be first, when open `mydomain/mymodule` will return `404`

Comment: if you use this '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>' then it will always find action in your site controller only. you can put all action in-----> '<action:(about|contact)|..|..|......>'

Comment: The generic approach won't work. This pattern `<action:\w+>` doesn't check the existence of action, it will simply treat everything that match expression `\w+` as action in site controller.